# Echo name not a number in case (choice). #bash

Tags: bash, case

I need to echo - the choice - from the case to a csv file.
When I echo varSel from below, I'm getting only the number and I want the "name" (sale or return in this case).
The while loop is here only to make to narrow user's choice. It's part of a bigger script, but as of now I only need this part to work, anything else does.

```
#! /bin/bash


while true; do
    echo    "1) sale"
    echo    "2) return"
    

    read -p "Choose your options: " varSel
    case ${varSel} in
    1) var1="sale"; break;;
    2) var1="return"; break;;
    *) echo "Choose options between 1 and 2";;
    esac
done

echo $varSel >> logfile.csv
```

Comment: Also, you should double-quote variable references (e.g. `echo "$var1"` instead of `echo $var1`). [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is good at spotting common mistakes like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another user already mentioned in the comments, you should `echo "$var1" >> logfile.csv` instead of `echo $varSel >> logfile.csv` in the last line of your script.

---

Another, more elaborate way would be to use an array containing possible choices as a basis to drive everything else (to illustrate, I added a few more choices):

```
#!/bin/bash

choices=("sale" "return" "somethingelse" "hello" "world")

while true; do

    # List possible choices
    for ((i=0; i < ${#choices[@]}; i++)); do
        echo "$((i+1))) ${choices[i]}"
    done

    # Prompt user to choose
    read -p "Choose your options: " varSel

    # Check if choice is valid, break loop if so
    # (varSel needs to be: non-empty, an integer and within range of possible choices)
    if [[ "${varSel}" != "" && "${varSel}" != *[!0-9]* ]] && (( ${varSel} >= 1 && ${varSel} <= ${#choices[@]} )); then
        choice="${choices[varSel-1]}"
        break
    else
        echo "Choose options between 1 and ${#choices[@]}"
    fi

done

echo "${choice}" >> logfile.csv
```

This can be used as a general template for any number of choices. The one tricky thing here is to keep track of choice numbers vs. array indices (choices are 1..n, array indices are 0..n-1).

Comment: It worked! As ridicules as it is, it was just the matter of putting var1 betweent " " like this "$var1"
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You're reinventing the builtin [`select`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-select) command:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PS3="Choose your options: "
select choice in sale return; do
    [[ -n $choice ]] && break
done
echo "$choice" >> logfile.csv
```

Comment: There can be good reasons to do so, e.g. if you want to have a default choice, different listing styles, keypress based choice... Personally, I find `select` rather limiting. But it would certainly suffice in the OP's use case.